# Highlight angular table cell content on mouseover and click

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to figure out how i can highlight the text/contents of the angular table cell when i mouseover and/or click on it

I went through the angular documentation here - https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives . But it seems to be pretty cumbersome. Any optimized or easy way to achieve this?

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let venue of venues[0]">
      <td (click)="onVenNameClick()" onMouseEnter() ></td>
      <td>{{venue.address}}</td>
      <td>{{venue.description}}</td>
      <td>{{venue.isactive}}</td>
      <td>{{venue.userid}}</td>
      <td>{{venue.displayid}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: look into https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer using CSS classes for these kind of feature in Angular, directives are created if u have to use the same functionality for a lot of components

```js
handleClickEvent() {
  // perform click operation
}
```

```css
.custom-venue td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: yellowgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.custom-venue td:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: yellowgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
    <tr class="custom-venue" *ngFor="let venue of venues[0]">
        <td (click)="handleClickEvent()">Handle Click</td>
        <td>{{venue.address}}</td>
        <td>{{venue.description}}</td>
        <td>{{venue.isactive}}</td>
        <td>{{venue.userid}}</td>
        <td>{{venue.displayid}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: that helped. Thank you!